# Scala returning option value

Tags: scala, return-value, scala-option

The problem is that I'd like this function to return option value (in form of Option[None]) or Option[something], but it only returns a Unit. What am I missing?

```
  def intersection(another: Interval){
     var test: Option[Interval] = None
    if (this.isLaterThan(another) || another.isLaterThan(this)){
       test
    }
     else {
       val a = this.start.later(another.start)
       val b = this.end.earlier(another.end)
       test=Some(new Interval(a, b))
       test
       
     }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing `=` before the first `{`. Methods defined without `=` always return `Unit`. Note that this syntax is actually deprecated precisely because this is a common error: https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-7605.

Answer (score 1):

you should specify the type it return

```
def intersection(another: Interval): Option[Interval] = {
    if (this.isLaterThan(another) || another.isLaterThan(this)){
       None
    }
     else {
       val a = this.start.later(another.start)
       val b = this.end.earlier(another.end)
       Some(new Interval(a, b))

     }
}
```

try not to use var in scala I change the code a bit